# output from shell_exec in php detect eol

Tags: php, python

I would like to analyse the different lines that I get from my php shell_exec. I have the following code:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("sudo python /home/pi/compteur/compteur.py -o /var/www/photo/photo -f 2>&1");

echo $output;
$output2 = explode ('\n',$output);
echo "<PRE>".$output2."</PRE>";
?>
```

So my python script is writing a lot of things and from the first echo, I see all the lines but in one line in the browser. With the explode, I have tried \n and other things but I don't get anything, the only thing I see from the second echo is Array and then nothing else. I would like to have the output as an array so that I can go over each line and take actions according to the result.

Comment: Your way works but you are removing the newlines.  Just loop thru the exploded array or try `exec()` with the second parameter.

Comment: @Richard do just  `print_r($output2)` and see what that gives you instead of `echo "<PRE>".$output2."</PRE>";` With PHP when you try to echo anything like arrays it will just say "Array" like you said, print_r is human readable and will print all the contents of the array

Comment: Ok, works better with exec(). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `exec()`  with the second parameter.